# cannot mount W95 FAT32 (LBA) partition type in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, mount, raspberry-pi

I am trying to mount W95 FAT32 (LBA) partition type into /mnt/data on my Raspbery Pi B+. Therefore, I've created this parttion and the current partition table is as follows:[image: Partition Table]
I've checked `proc/filesystems` for a list of supported partition types and here is a listing:[image: Supported Files Systems]. Now, I've tried to mount `mmcblk0p3` partition as `vfat` and `msdos` type and I always get error:[image: Mount Error]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried mounting without the `-t` option? It should auto-detect the filesystem.

Comment: I have now, same error.

Comment: Is mmcblk0p1 mounted/mountable? Anything in the logs?

Comment: Does `file -s /dev/mmcblk0p3` show that there's anything like a FAT32 filesystem there?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I've tried that now, it shows: 
`[root@octopus ~]# file -s /dev/mmcblk0p3
/dev/mmcblk0p3: data
[root@octopus ~]#`

Comment: If you do `strings /dev/mmcblk0p3 | more` or `strings -e l /dev/mmcblk0p3 | more` do you see anything that looks like a portion of the files you think ought to be in that filesystem? What operating system wrote the files in that filesystem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I've created the partition and it is emtpy, java application WILL create files on it and write some data to these files. Command `strings -e l /dev/mmcblk0p3 | more` displays some garbage: `[root@octopus ~]# clear && strings -e l /dev/mmcblk0p3 | more
,"#!
7@888
4T5L5D5@58505
.\2H2
+P+D+
`(p(
(p(h(
P(@(
8&@&
 #(#
#+3;CScs
!1Aa
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4       (
4Ddt
4Ddt
4Ddt
 @`p
0Digitized data copyright
 2007, Google Corporation.Droid SerifBoldAscender - Droid Serif`. The text is to long.

Comment: What operating system is this java application running on? Android?

Comment: Have you created a filesystem on the partition? The `file` command returns `data` on an empty (unformatted) partition, while it returns a long description if a filesystem has been created: `x86 boot sector, mkdosfs boot message display, code offset 0x3c, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat",`

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the relevant codepage? grep CONFIG_NLS_CODE /boot/config-`uname -r`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I've allocated empty space for partition using `fdisk`, but I did not **make filesystem**, **format it** and then **mount it** using `mkfs.vfat /dev/mmcblk0p3` and `mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt/data`. Now works ok!